# How to add Character(163) checkboxes in blank column using range from an active cell to last entry of another column (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, range

I am trying to add checkboxes using a character key (163) in a blank column using the range from an active cell to the last entry of another column, but so far, I can only use this code in an empty column which goes onto to infinity:

```
Sub Add_Check_Box()

'fill range for demo
    If Range("A2") = "" Then
        With Range("A:A")
            .Value = Chr(163)
            .Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
            .Font.Size = 40
        End With
        Exit Sub
    End If

'toggle the value in column B
    If Not Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        With Target
            If .Value = Chr(163) Then .Value = Chr(82) Else .Value = Chr(163)
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried using the following syntaxes:

```
 Range(Range("B2"), Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Select
Range("A2:J2", Range("A2:J2").End(xlDown))
```

in place of:

```
With Range("A:A")
```

Comment: `Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target)` what is `Target` ?

Comment: Looks as if you copied the code from an event routine (likely `Change`), where `Target` is passed as parameter and tells the code which cell(s) where affected. Your routine doesn't know `Target`. Either pass the cell as parameter from whereever your code is called, or maybe change `Target` to `ActiveCell` which then will work on the current active cell (the cell that has the focus).

Comment: did you mean? `Sub add()
For Each cell In Range("A2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row)
If cell.Value = Chr(163) Then cell.Value = Chr(82) Else cell.Value = Chr(163)
Next
End Sub
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to duplicate column A and then write over it to stay within the range of the last row of data from the other columns.

```
  Sub Add_Check_Box()
Range("A:A").Copy
Range("B:B").Insert
' fill range
    
        With Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
            .Value = Chr(163)
            .Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
            .Font.Size = 56
        End With
        
        
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "CHECK IF DONE"

End Sub
```